# How can erase things after specific text..?

Tags: python, string

How can remove after specific text..?

ex)
text(Column name) 
abc__22
E_abcd
dcba
dsdvs
bfbfdd__23
dsfbbb
sdfdf

so I want to erase everything after that, including particular text(__)

text(Column name) 
abc
E_abcd
dcba
dsdvs
bfbfdd
dsfbbb
sdfdf

please reply it.. if you have enough time for me.. thanks a lot

Comment: I tried it but it's not work

# df1['text'] = df1['text'].apply(lambda x : x[0].split('__')[:-1])

Answer (score 0):

the easiest method:

```
text = “hi_hello”

# i wanna del all texts after hi so result might be hi, using selector method
print(text[0:2])
# output : hi

text = “handsome! Hi”
print(text[0:9])
# output : handsome!
```

Comment: so this will replace "abc__22" with "abc22" instead of just "abc"

Comment: you mean need to erase all after the word abc?
ok i will edit my post

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda and split to get results.
Here is the example

```
df
        Courses   
0     Spark__12  
1  Py_Spark__33  

output:

df["new_column"]=df["column"].apply(lambda x:x.split("__")[0])

>>> df
        Courses  new_column
0     Spark__12  Spark
1  Py_Spark__33  Py_Spark
```